# What is the defference between `com.example.**` and `com.example.**{*;}`?

Tags: android, proguard

When I use ProGuard, what is the defference between `com.example.**` and `com.example.**{*;}` ?
For example, what happens for each cases?

```
  -keep class com.example.**

  -keep class com.example.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> -keep class com.example.**

Keep all classes in `com.example` package

> -keep class com.example.** { *; }

Keep all inner classes as well in `com.example` package

Comment: hi, i would like to get your attention to this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35539960/how-to-get-release-build-apk-file-using-proguard, your help would be greatly appreciated